# Is there a machanism in ODP.NET to postpone sending queries until commit?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, transactionscope

Consider I have a list of 1000 queries consists of `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations. I want to run them in a transaction.

Also I don't want to send each query to the database individually because of 1000x round trip time.

Is there any mechanism to tell ODP.NET to keep the queries in memory, after then send the whole queries with one aggregated query on commit (so 1 round trip time)

A simple(stupid!?) solution is to create a large text query in a local variable pragmatically and after then pass it to command and execute it.

It's obvious that in this way there will be no lock before sending queries which doesn't matter in my situation.

Comment: Use stored procedures. Create one, whether as part of a package(preferred) or a standalone, place all your DMLs, which should be part of a transaction, and call that stored procedure.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov the problem is that the query is dynamically generated. It's not a fixed query.

Comment: I would ask for more information, then, and an example. Who, when, and how those DMLs are being generated. And I think you can simply enclose those DMLs in `begin end` block even if they are being dynamically generated.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov There an ORM (Object Relation Mapper) created the query. When `object.Persist()` is called the ORM traverses the Object Graph and creates appropriate queries due to each object node's state. Each type has different graph and each instance's graph nodes have different states.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov as a matter of fact I've already used `begin end` blocks. I've described it in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257429/why-this-pl-sql-query-doesnt-execute-using-odp-net
But it seems stupid, besides it's not stable. For example in the link I have problem with an strange behavior of ODP.NET

Comment: The DMLs you generate will be all a single transaction? Like you want them to be commited/rollbacked all together?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar yes, they should run in a single transaction. But I don't want [100 query, 100 network round trips, 1 transaction]. I want [100 query, 1 network round trip, 1 transaction]

Comment: Is it possible to generate the dynamic DML on server side instead of in the client?

Comment: Is it that you know, from bitterly hard-won experience, that the round-trip delay will slow you down, or is this something you're concerned about because a friend of the guy down the hall thought he heard someone say something about it in passing at a party last Tuesday? What I'm getting at is that it would be very unusual for network time to noticeably affect the time to execute these statements. Perhaps you're hooked to the net via a 300 baud dial-up modem - I expect they still exist..?

Comment: @Wernfried no it's not possible. Because the ORM generates the required query using state of the client's object graph.

Comment: @BobJarvis unfortunately in my situation removing round trip is important. Consider `RTT=10ms` Having 1000 queries individually makes the total 'RTT' 10000ms and running them as one bunch makes `RTT` 10ms. And I think that it makes sense to work on removing this time. As a matter of fact the bandwidth is not the only QoS parameter affecting the performance. The latency is important too.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a procedure with an associative array parameter. Put all DML into this array, send it to DB and execute them in a loop. I have an example in VB.NET:

```
Public Sub DynamicDML()
   Dim cmd As OracleCommand
   Dim par As OracleParameter
   Dim DML As New List(Of String), dmlArray As String()

   DML.Add("DELETE FROM TABLE_A")
   DML.Add"INSERT INTO TABLE_B VALUES (...)")
   DML.Add("UPDATE TABLE_C SET ...")
   dmlArray = DML.ToArray

   cmd = New OracleCommand("BEGIN MyProcedure(:lines); END;", server.con)
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

   par = cmd.Parameters.Add("lines", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input)
   par.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray
   par.Value = dmlArray 
   par.Size = dmlArray.Length
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

End Sub
```

On Oracle side:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE DML_PACKAGE AS
    TYPE TArrayOfVarchar2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    PROCEDURE MyProcedure(lines IN TArrayOfVarchar2);
END DML_PACKAGE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DML_PACKAGE AS

PROCEDURE MyProcedure(lines IN TArrayOfVarchar2) IS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN lines.FIRST..lines.LAST LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lines(i);
    END LOOP;
END MyProcedure;

END DML_PACKAGE;
/
```

Anyway, I doupt that a single action of an end user can trigger 1000 **different** DML statements which have to be generated individually one by one. I am pretty sure most of them could be done by Triggers, Constraints, Procedures, bulk operations, etc.

Comment: As a matter of fact I was using same approach. But I want to send parameters using Parameters not raw query. (To avoid SQL Injection)

Comment: @mehrandvd, then I am back to my fist comment: Try to generate the statements (as much as possible) on the server side instead of on the client side.